# Which websocket sampler is used to perform load testing on a websocket based chat application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, automation-testing

I have a Websocket Based chat application and I want to perform testing on it, In which I want fire 'hi' message from 10 users to a same destination. but I'm not sure which sampler should I use.

Please someone let me know which websocket sampler should I use.

Answer (score 0):

The most advanced plugin which provides WebSockets protocol support to JMeter is [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)

With regards to "which websocket sampler" - we don't know, you need to take a look at Network tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and configure JMeter to simulate the same network footprint as your real browser does (the same applies to desktop application if it's not a browser)

There is [`socket.io-chatserversample.jmx` demo script](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/socket.io-chatserversample.jmx) which you can use as a reference. Additionally you can take a look at [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) article which provides comprehensive explanation of installation and usage processes.